# put awk or grep output to command line arguments in bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I'm pretty new to shell programming and I'm trying to write a shell script to assign grep or awk pattern filtering output to command line parameter in bash shell.

```
    a.sh
    source ./b.sh
    called a function like // a(function name) parameter1 parameter2

    b.sh
    function a{
    $2=grep -ai "some string" a.txt(parameter 1)
    echo "$2"
     }
```

I wanna do like, but it won't let me to do it.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Read the man page section on command substitution.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you cannot set positional parameters in a way that the caller can read that value. If you want to 'return' a string from a function, you must write it to stdout, like so:

```
function myfunc()
{
    echo "test"
}

VAR=$(myfunc)
```

When the above code is run, `VAR` will contain the string 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

For reference questions, look at the `man` pages; for example, `man bash`, `man grep` etc. For internal shell commands like `function` there's a `bash` built-in with similar functionality called `help`, for example `help function`.

To set positional parameters, you can use the built-in `set`. For example, `set -- "a b" "c d"` sets `$1` to `a b` and `$2` to `c d`.

For a pragmatic introduction to `bash` programming see the [Bash wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/). It's simply the best Bash resource out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to positional parameters, but you can do something like this:

```
function myf {
   #do something with $1,$2, etc
}

FOO=$(awk command)
BAR=$(other command)

myf $FOO $BAR  #the function will use $FOO and $BAR as $1 and $2 positional parameters
```

So you can pass the content of those commands to the function `myf` through the use of variables (`FOO` and `BAR`) in this case.
You could even do it without dummy variables calling `myf $(some command)` but the way I wrote it improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try function, try a script first.

```
#!/bin/sh
arg1=${1?'Missing argument'}
grep -ai "some string"  $arg1
```

And then put this script in your ~/bin folder (make sure you have changed your PATH directory to include ~/bin

Then just execute the script. 
If you really need a function, then do

```
#!/bin/sh
b() {
    grep -ai "some string" $1
}

b filename
```

Comment: My example gave an error if an argument was not provided, but this may not be what you want. The script could be a simplified `grep -ai "some string"  $1` - which allows you to use it with no arguments, e.g. `cat file*.txt | script`